# Action/metadata line 1 contains an unknown parameter _type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement bulk upload in elasticsearch with `node.js`.

While uploading data I'm facing errors like:

```
"error": {
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "failed to parse field [_id] of type [_id] in document with id 'id'. Preview of field's value: 'id'"
}
```

My sample code as below

```
const result = elastic_client.bulk({
   body: [{
      index: {
         _index: indexName,
         _id: "62c13eeac784c2753c0ca4a0"
      },
      _type: "62c13eeac784c2753c0ca4a0 } {
      "firstName": "Paul",
      "lastName": "Deo",
      "gender": "Male"
   }]
}, function (err, resp) {
   if (resp) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(resp, null, '\t'));
   }
   if (err) {
      console.log(err, "err>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
   }
});
```